# how do i check two request.form elements to see if they are equal in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

```
if (len(request.form['password']) == len(request.form['confirm_password']))
        flash("password must be equal to your confirm password", 'password', 'confirm_password')
```

I am creating a reg form for classwork.  I want to set this validation to check if the passwords are equal.  I think thats how you right it, but it is giving me a syntax error.  if you guys can point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: just noticed i misspelled write -___-

Comment: You need a colomn (`:`) with your `if` statement...

Comment: except from syntax error. why did you compare password with its length instead of value?

Comment: how would you compare the passwords directly? check if both are equal to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colon after if, fix the indenting.

(And you should probably check that password and confirm password are actually equal, not just the same length, but thats not what you asked)...

```
if (len(request.form['password']) == len(request.form['confirm_password'])):
    flash("password must be equal to your confirm password", 'password', 'confirm_password')
```

Comment: Again is this mine?, i am just saying, no need to delete